# Pandas: Concat DataFrames with Unexpected Behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some work in Pandas and getting strange behavior when using `pd.concat`.  Specifically, I have a DataFrame, `df`, and I'm one-hot encoding the `zipcode` column.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
zip_encoded = label_binarizer.transform(df["zipcode"])        
zip_encoded = pd.DataFrame(zip_encoded, columns=label_binarizer.classes_)
df = df.drop("zipcode", axis=1)
print("df shape:", df.shape)
print("zip encoded shape:", zip_encoded.shape)
result = pd.concat([df, zip_encoded], axis=1)
print("result shape", result.shape)
return label_binarizer, result
```

This gives the following output:

```
df shape: (13999, 13)
zip encoded shape: (13999, 10)
result shape (14000, 23)
```

So I'm just trying to concat along the columns and I expect a result shape of `(13999, 23)` but instead I see a shape of `(14000, 23)`.

I do the same thing with my `test_df` by using the `LabelBinarizer` that I fit on my `df`.  When I do that, I get the even stranger:

```
df shape: (1000, 13)
zip encoded shape: (1000, 10)
result shape (2000, 23)
```

When I inspect the new `test_df`, all of the non-zipcode columns are filled with NaNs...

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that the row names are the same in both dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need add `index` from df when you create `zip_encoded`

```
zip_encoded = label_binarizer.transform(df["zipcode"])        
zip_encoded = pd.DataFrame(zip_encoded, columns=label_binarizer.classes_,index=df.index)
```

Then doing the concat

```
df = df.drop("zipcode", axis=1)
result = pd.concat([df, zip_encoded], axis=1)
```

Example , you df index may not from 0 to `len(df)`, when you create the df without setting the `index` , default is from 0 to `len(df)` range , that is why after `concat` , the shape different

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2]},index=[0,1])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2]},index=[1,2])
print(pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1))
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2]},index=df1.index)
print(pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1))
     A    A
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  1.0
2  NaN  2.0
   A  A
0  1  1
1  2  2
```

Comment: What does adding `index` do in this case?

Comment: @bclayman pd.concat default is outer , when the index is different they outer merge the two df , I will add the example

Comment: This is right *if* the dataframes should have the same indices in the same order.  Which may be OP's use case.  But if that's not the case, and the second dataframe's index is meaningful, this would cause problems.